# LTspice simulation with capacitors

Tags: voltage, capacitor, analog

I have this circuit simulated in LTspice :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fn7T2W.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here is the graph:

[image]

Why does the current flowing through R2 do that thing in the beginning (it rises and then starts to be reduced.) Shouldn't it be graphed similarly to IC1?

Comment: Can you explain why you think it shouldn’t?

Comment: Well, you've really managed to mess things up in your question -- despite good intentions. Your circuit has labeled parts that don't match your LTspice run. I also gather that you must have used UIC in your .TRAN, or things would be quite different. Your I(R3) current in your LTspice plot is the current for R1 in your schematic. Clearly, your LTspice schematic part labels are just different. That's all.

Comment: Please show how the voltages and currents in your graph are defined on the schematic and what transient directive you are using. Probably the simulation starts with zero charge on all capacitors.

Comment: Please make sure your plots are consistent with the schematic. Your data shows a trace for "I(C3)" but there is no such capacitor in your schematic. It would be best to show us the actual LTspice schematic, including the simulation commands.

Comment: Sorry, I don't trust your added schematic anymore. Show us the **actual LTspice schematic**.

Comment: Better! Now I(R3) can easily be explained. At first, C1's voltage is 0 V. So the full 10 V is across R3. As time proceeds, the capacitors charge up with C1 reaching 5 V eventually and thus I(R3) falls back to 50 mA with only 5 V across it.

Answer (score 0):

Because C2 is a short circuit at t = 0.

At t = infinite IR2 goes to zero.

At t = infinite IR3 goes to 50 mA because there is a conductive path for DC current.

IR3 has a peak at the beginning because C1 is a short circuit that steals current to R1. The current peak in R3 is V1/R3 = 100 mA.

Comment: Yeah. But if you look at the plot Miss Mulan provides, it goes to 50 mA at infinity. Miss Mulan just hasn't provided us with the right schematic that matches what was used with LTspice.